# Java org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser and XML External Entity (XXE) Processing Attacks

Tags: penetration-test, java, android, xml

I'm evaluating the security of an Android application and the application is using the [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) included with Android.

I'm having some difficulty getting any [common attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing) to work, but I want to be sure I haven't missed any possibilities.  What are the minimum requirements/features this parser needs to have enabled for XXE processing attacks to be successful?

In particular I am looking at whether the features for XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES and XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL are enabled or not.

Answer (score 4):

Well I can answer my own question now, at least in part.

The application I was examining has a default instance of XmlPullParser with only FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES disabled.  I was able to get the [Billion Laughs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs) entity attack to work.  My issue what I was not putting the entity in the right child element of the expected XML response.